# How the heck did “Community” user/bot close this dupe question?

Tags: support

[This question is a question I voted to close](https://superuser.com/q/1735211/167207) because the solution was a hunch I suggested in the comments. The [original poster confirmed my hunch](https://superuser.com/questions/1735211/inconsistent-dns-resolution-in-macos-monterey-12-5#comment2686724_1735211) and I then voted to close as dupe as a result.

Okay, that is normal: Something gets flagged, others vote and a question closes (or languishes but that is another story).

But today I saw something different. Maybe I never noticed this before, but it seems like my close vote was then confirmed and sealed by the “Community” user/bot. How the heck did that happen?

I assume the internal workings of Stack Exchange moderation logic is kept deliberately opaque, but is this now a normal thing? I assume machine learning of some sort was used to compare questions or even check comments?

Screenshot below of the notice for reference.

[image]

Comment: Most likely the original poster also voted to close the question as a duplicate as well. As the original poster lacks the privileges to close questions Community stepped in instead. I thought we had a question about this already but I can't find it.

Comment: Found it, apparently the asker gets a "yep that did it" button and then Community does the job.

Comment: As you say it's a nice quick interface that removes the need of waiting for 4 more people to go "yeah that's a dupe" and lets the author close the loop. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250922/can-we-clarify-to-the-op-that-their-question-is-not-yet-closed-and-the-duplicate/250930#250930 shows the UI and it looks quite nice to be honest. Also explains why we get snarky "urgh, the dupe doesn't answer my question you idiots" edits occasionally.